# Uma conexão com o servidor foi estabelecida com êxito, mas ocorreu um erro durante o processo de logon

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, conexão

Olá pessoal estou com um problema ao tentar realizar a conexão com um banco de dados via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio porém é exibida a seguinte mensagem de erro:

**Uma conexão com o servidor foi estabelecida com êxito, mas ocorreu um erro durante o processo de logon. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Erro: 10054)
Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto**

O curioso que eu tento em outra máquina e consigo conectar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -4):

No console de login do Management Studio, clique em opções na parte inferior da janela e marque a caixa "Certificado de servidor confiável".